# phoneGap iOS custom plugin not called

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have made a custom demo plugin in phoneGap for iOS but it's not getting called.

Here is what I have done so far:

adobeCustom.js

```
  var cordova = require('cordova');

function AdobePlugin() {}

AdobePlugin.prototype.editImage = function(imageUri, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'AdobePlugin', 'editImage', [imageUri]);
    }
};

cordova.addConstructor(function() {
    if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
    window.plugins.adobePlugin = new AdobePlugin();
});
```

PGAdobeCreative.m //plugin file

```
    #import <AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation/AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation.h>
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKImage/AdobeCreativeSDKImage.h>
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKImage/AdobeUXImageEditorViewController.h>
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation/AdobeUXAuthManager.h>

#import "PGAdobeCreativeSDKFoundation.h"
#import "NSObject+PropertiesAsDictionary.h"
#import "NSArray+ItemAsDictionary.h"


@interface PGAdobeCreativeSDKFoundation () <AdobeUXImageEditorViewControllerDelegate>

@end
@implementation PGAdobeCreativeSDKFoundation

#define ADOBE_CSDK_CLIENT_ID       @"5587f31263dc4f3id"
#define ADOBE_CSDK_CLIENT_SECRET   @"81292c83-eec7-key"

- (void)editImage:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image test"
                                                    message:@"called"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;


}
@end
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/adobeCustom.js"></script>
<button id='getFileContents' onclick="window.plugins.adobePlugin.editImage('imagename')">Click here</button>
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: You need to follow the cordova plugin spec and create an actual plugin (with plugin.xml, etc.) and install the plugin w/ `cordova plugin add path_to_plugin_dir`

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Thanks but can you please provide more details on how to do that... I mean do I need to create a custom plugin and add it through command line, that's what you are saying?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, that's not really necesary

Comment: @z22, you have to add the plugin to your config.xml